# CakePHP - staying on the same page

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a simple controller for adding a row into table but I would like to stay on the same page with if it fails but only with flash warning message.

```
class WarehouseAddressesController{
    public function itemToAdd($id = null){
        $exists = $this->ItemsAddress->find('first', array('conditions' => array(
            'warehouse_addresses_id' => $this->request->data['WarehouseAddress']['id'],
            'items_id' => $this->request->data['Items']['itemToAdd'])));

        if($this->request->is(array('post')) && empty($exists)){
            $data = array(
                'warehouse_addresses_id' => $this->request->data['WarehouseAddress']['id'],
                'items_id' => $this->request->data['Items']['itemToAdd']
            );

            if ($this->ItemsAddress->save($data, array('validate' => 'first',))) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('This item has been successfully added to the requested address.'));
                $this->redirect($this->referer());
            }
            if(!empty($exists)){
                $this->Flash->warning(__('This item already exists on this address'));
                $this->redirect($this->referer());
            }
            else {
                $this->Flash->error(__('This item could not be added to this address. Please, try again.'));
                $this->redirect($this->referer());
            }}}}
```

When Item is saved it stays on the same page like it should using $this->referer, but when item exists, it shows error Error: The view for WarehouseAddressesController::itemToAdd() was not found.
But I would like to stay on the page and just show error that the page exists.

Comment: Never redirect unless the save was successful. Basic PRG pattern rule. Until then it will by design stay on the same page and keep also the form filled out. You should respect this coding pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I just had to add return $this->redirect($this->referer()); in first if block and in last if block.

Comment: No, if it fails, just return from the function instead of doing any redirect. Your redirect adds extra round-trips to the server.